# Atmega bootloader - Cant upload sketch twice

Tags: arduino, bootloader, atmega

I have an atmega 2560 on my own PCB. Its UART is connected to an FTDI chip.
When I burn the Bootlader on the atmega via the SPI pins, I can upload a sketch over the Arduino IDE over USB, but this only works once. I always have to burn the bootloader again before uploading a sketch.

Does anyone know how to solve this Problem?

Specs:
Atmega Clock 16MHz external Oscillator
HIGH Fuse: 0xD8
EXTENDED Fuse: 0xFD
LOW Fuse: 0xFF
Lock Bits: 0xCF

Comment: Without knowing which bootloader we can just guess. What about read yout the flash over SPI and check if the bootloader is still there. Or take a look into it's source code and find out when it starts the main program.

Comment: I am using the bootloader, from the arduino boards.txt file. There it says, the stk500boot_v2_mega2560.hex file is the correct bootloader

Comment: Maybe you don't have proper reset circuit (again, no schematics here). Those bootloaders won't jump into the main program section if it's empty (and after burning the bootloader over ISP it is). After that you have to reset MCU - then you have second or more to start the upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem thanks to KIIV

At first the program is being compiled and after that uploaded.
Between these two steps, right before it tries to upload, you have to press the reset button and then it uploads.

Its a little bit tricky

Comment: add a reset circuit